# Hover multiple elements affecting only 1 item

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi guys i was wondering if there is a way to hover a  few elements with the same class name which is placed side by side and actions would be trigger upon leaving the area of the elements.  For example :

```
<div class="hoverme"></div>
<div class="hoverme"></div>
<div class="hoverme"></div>
<div class="hoverme"></div>
<div class="hoverme"></div>
```

the javascript of "unhover" below should only be called when they leave the whole area of "hoverme" class.

```
$('.hoverme').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
            if (event.type == 'mouseover') {

                if(!$("#stage1 td").hasClass("hover"))
                {
                    $("#stage1 td").addClass("hover",200)
                }   
            } 
            else {

                //$("#stage1 td").removeClass("hover",200)

            }
        });
```

Is there a way for this action??

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the shape of the div is not just purely square. It consist of a few squares but in the end the shape is rather odd. So i could not be wrapping my divs with another parent div.

i am using jquery ui therefore i am able to addclass and removeclass with the second parameter

Comment: could you show us where is #stage1 td?

Comment: Why are you passing a second parameter to .addClass()? It only takes one parameter, either a string or a function.

Comment: @JeffRobertDagala err i would say the #stage1 td would be the least matter im worried about. it is to make the td background coloured.

ianpgall: i am using jqueryui therefore am able to use the second parameters. Edited the post mentioning that now

Comment: someone voted down this post...wonder if you could let me know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a mix of the previous answers.

- Use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover and mouseout.
- Secondly, you **can** use a wrapper div, and this is how I made it work. If you're hovering over a child div, you're hovering over its parent as well, regardless of where that parent is. A mouseleave event on the parent div won't trigger until you're no longer hovering over any of the children.

I tried creating a zero-sized wrapper div with five child divs absolutely positioned into the shape of a cross, and I believe it works the way you say you need it to. Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

```
$('.hoverme-wrapper').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
    if(!$("#stage1 td").hasClass("hover")) 
      $("#stage1 td").addClass("hover", 200)
  } else {
    $("#stage1 td").removeClass("hover", 200);
  }
```

[edited to confirm I've tested against jQuery UI addClass implementation]

Comment: it works because u are just doing addClass("hover")

if you happen to read the post properly, i had another parameter addClass("hover",200). once the mouseleaves, it still can see the different state for the stage1 td

Comment: I incorporated jQuery UI into my test, and it still works fine. Can you supply clearer information on the error you're getting? Post some example css? It might be your method of positioning that's setting you awry.

Comment: i got it working. perhaps i misunderstood or something earlier. Thank you!!

Comment: Great! I've edited my answer a bit - on re-reading I think the key point was a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

try this: `live()` is deprecated you can use `on()` method:

```
$('.hoverme').on('mouseover', function(event) {
   $("#stage1 td").addClass("hover")
}).on('mouseout', function() {
   $("#stage1 td").removeClass("hover")
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jUmTt/

Comment: In this form, `.on()` isn't a `.live()` replacement; however as long as this code is in the document ready function and the "hoverme"-classed elements are not destroyed and replaced, it will work!

Comment: like i have edited the post...try adding another parameter to the addclass and removeclass

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean whenever they hover over any of the elements they all recieve the `hover` class? Try this:

```
var elements = $('.hoverme');
elements.on('hover', function(event) {
  event.type == 'mouseover' ? elements.addClass('hover') : elements.removeClass('hover');
});
```

Alternatively, you can restructure your HTML to wrap the hover-able elements, i.e.:

```
<div class="hoverWrap">
  <div class="hoverme"></div>
  <div class="hoverme"></div>
  <div class="hoverme"></div>
  <div class="hoverme"></div>
  <div class="hoverme"></div>
</div>
```

And then attach the hover event listener to `hoverWrap`. Semantically this makes more sense; just because the elements are close to each other in the markup doesn't mean they should be treated as one large element.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, but I think you're trying to do this:

```
var timer;
$('.hoverme').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if(!$("#stage1 td").hasClass("hover")) {
            $("#stage1 td").addClass("hover")
        }   
    } else {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#stage1 td").removeClass("hover");
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: it is not working well. adeneo add another paramter for the addclass and removeclass...im am using jqueryui...there is an option for it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`.